# RadioButtonList to change table's visiblity

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a radiobutton list.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList" runat="server"
 TextAlign="Right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="cb">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and In the code part,

```
        ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Visible", "visible"));
        ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hidden", "hidden"));
        ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and this is my table,

```
<table align="center" runat="server" id="OdemeTable" visible="false">
     <tr>
          <td>
              Hello world!
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

If I select the visible option from RadioButtonList, I want OdemeTable to be shown dynamically but if a select hidden from RadioButtonList, OdemeTable should be gone. How can I achieve this with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList').click(function () {
                if ($("#ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList input:radio:checked").val() == 'hidden') {
                    document.getElementById('OdemeTable').style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('OdemeTable').style.display = "";
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>


    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList" runat="server"
        TextAlign="Right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="cb">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Visible" Value="visible"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Hidden" Value="hidden"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <table align="center" id="OdemeTable" style="display:none" >
     <tr>
          <td>
              Hello world!
          </td>
     </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
```

Note that you should not make the table `Visible=false` by default on serverside since that means that it won't be rendered on clientside at all. So you won't be able to make it visible then. Therefor i used `style="display:none"`.

Comment: Just as an @:
1) You have to care with the IDs of runat="server" controls in JS when using asp.net. The server will generate other IDs in some cases (UserControls,...)
2) Because of this you should not make the table runat="server" (@Mehmet). It is always better not to make controls runat="server" when they are not needed in code behind!

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer: My table is not `runat=server`. If OP needs to access it from serverside he should use [`ClientIdMode=Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

Comment: Just hitted "RETURN" where I wanted to make a linkebreak and was editig the comment... sorry :P

ClientIdMode=Static is an option, but be shure not to use the same id in different controls which are used at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

Javascript

```
function HideTable() {
            var RB1 = document.getElementById("<%=ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList.ClientID%>");
            var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");

            var tbl = document.getElementById("<%=OdemeTable.ClientID%>");

            var selval;

            for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
                if (radio[i].checked) {
                    selval = radio[i].value; 
                }
            }

            if (selval == 'Visible') {
                document.getElementById("<%=OdemeTable.ClientID%>").style.display = '';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("<%=OdemeTable.ClientID%>").style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
```

ASPX

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ChangeVisibilityRadioButtonList" runat="server" onchange="HideTable();" TextAlign="Right"
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Visible" Text="Visible"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Hidden" Text="Hidden"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <table align="center" runat="server" id="OdemeTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Hello world!</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```